# KDE and LightDM on ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, kde, lightdm, kdm

Is it possible to use LightDM with KDE on Archlinux? Wiki says

> Basically there are two ways of starting KDE. Using KDM or xinitrc.

I use also awesome WM and XFCE, so I'd like to use LightDM instead.

Comment: They have a LightDM page but it's not very obvious. Take a look at [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM)...

Comment: kdm was deprecated years ago, unless they brought it back from the dead. sddm I believe is what was used to replace it, which was in turn fairly buggy and unreliable, but it may be better today.

Comment: @Lizardx the question is from years ago. Got just digged out.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that. However it's worth correcting anyway, since kdm doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah man! Everything is possible with Archlinux! You can install the entire system anyway you want.

First, if you just installed Archlinux with no [display manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/display_manager) or a [desktop environment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_environment), you have just to install

```
sudo pacman -S xorg xinit
sudo pacman -S lightdm lightdm-kde-greeter
sudo pacman -S plasma
```

after that you have to enable the service that control the lightdm on the boot time

```
sudo systemctl enable lightdm.service
sudo systemctl start lightdm.service
```

If you are using a display manager you don't need to worry about the ***.xinitrc*** file cause the display manager is accountable for start the desktop environment that you chose.

Second, if you have an [Display manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/display_manager) installed, like GDM, SDDM or XDM, you have to stop the service running, for example the GDM service

```
sudo systemclt disable gdm.service
```

and select the new display manager to start with the system boot

```
sudo systemctl enable lightdm.service
```

The display manager is independent of the [desktop environment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_environment) such as KDE or Gnome, so you can arrange the combination between display manager and desktop environment the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but notice that the question was asked more than 4 years ago :D I switched to more stable environment (nowadays I work, you know?)

Comment: And it's a poor answer, since it doesn't actually answer the question, it's just a generic formula for install and enable of a dm, it doesn't actually know or say if that particular dm can run or start KDE itself.

Comment: Sorry enedil! I don't realized the date of the question, really sorry.

Comment: Lizardx the question is "Is it possible to use LightDM with KDE on Archlinux?"

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, as already stated by the other answer (not sure why all that hate). KDE devs even seem to explicitly [care](https://phabricator.kde.org/D11478) about it from time to time.

Lightdm-kde-greeter has since been [purged](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/commit/?id=e481523462830be14af15d8e405ee41411f297ef) though, [probably](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1065796-start-0.html#8087444) since it was still Qt4-based after years of abandonment (as a result of Ubuntu's Mir [detour](http://blog.davidedmundson.co.uk/blog/kde-lightdm-and-the-mir-kerfuffle/), and KDE efforts [moving](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=285&t=120902#p309250) to SDDM).

I don't really know how the [built-in](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/tree/master/liblightdm-qt) `liblightdm-qt5` fares (or the other [qt](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/795) [greeters](https://github.com/rezso/lightdm-qt5-greeter)), but funnily enough you can just use `lightdm-gtk-greeter` to get them working together.

Comment: I can't evaluate this answer as for now, I don't use ArchLinux, I don't use KDE, and the answer probably is not accurate (just because the question is too old). Sorry man

Comment: Thank you! This was the key for me to use `lightdm-gtk-greeter`. I worked to login to KDE right after install. https://github.com/KDE/lightdm says to use lightdm-kde-greeter, but apt and myself couldnt find it.. it looks like it might be redhat RPM.

Answer (score -2):

If possible, use lightdm to start kde and bspwm.

Install the arch with bspwm first, and then kde.
Sddm was not enabled.