# Cant get to SDDM login screen, startx works - KDE on Ubuntu server

Tags: kde, startx, sddm

A similar question was asked, but did not solve if startx is working: [Sddm is not starting but in theory everything is working!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586302/sddm-is-not-starting-but-in-theory-everything-is-working)

`echo 'exec /usr/bin/startplasma-x11' > ~/.xinitrc` worked to make `startx` start KDE on top of Ubuntu server. SDDM status is active, and used `dpkg-reconfigure sddm` however I still have blinking cursor on tty1 and tty7+. (This is inside KVM/virt-mgr, but shouldnt matter). `startx` starts Kubuntu DE, but still cant get to login screen by using logout. Am using `sddm --example-config > /etc/sddm.conf` for default config. I checked `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/sddm.log`. I also tried with `sddm &` and then `startx &`.

```
[13:02:04.305] (II) DAEMON: Initializing...
[13:02:04.313] (II) DAEMON: Starting...
[13:02:04.313] (II) DAEMON: Logind interface found
```

```
[   616.035] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   616.036] Build Operating System: linux Ubuntu
[   616.036] Current Operating System: Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-100-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 3 18:43:29 UTC 2022 x86_64
[   616.036] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-100-generic root=UUID=5d51cbd2-a1de-48f6-b8b6-00709c787fa0 ro gfxpayload=1920x1080x32
[   616.036] Build Date: 14 December 2021  02:14:13PM
[   616.036] xorg-server 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   616.036] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
[   616.036]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   616.036] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   616.037] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Feb 19 13:02:13 2022
[   616.038] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   616.038] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   616.038] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   616.038] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   616.038] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   616.038] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[   616.038] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   616.038] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   616.038] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   616.038] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   616.038] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   616.038] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   616.038]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   616.038] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   616.038]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   616.038] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   616.038]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   616.038] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   616.038]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   616.038] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   616.038]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   616.038] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
[   616.038] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   616.038] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   616.038] (II) Loader magic: 0x55eb5ab29020
[   616.038] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   616.038]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   616.038]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[   616.038]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   616.038]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   616.040] (--) using VT number 2

[   616.040] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[   616.044] (--) PCI:*(0@0:1:0) 1af4:1050:1af4:1100 rev 1, Mem @ 0xfc000000/8388608, 0xfd800000/16384, 0xfea14000/4096, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   616.044] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   616.045] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   616.046] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   616.046]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 1.0.0
[   616.046]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   616.047] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[   616.047] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   616.047] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[   616.047] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   616.047] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   616.047] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   616.047] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   616.047]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 1.20.13
[   616.047]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   616.047]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[   616.047] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   616.047] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   616.047] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   616.047]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.5.0
[   616.047]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   616.047]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   616.047] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   616.047] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   616.047] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   616.047]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 2.4.0
[   616.047]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   616.047]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   616.047] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   616.047] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   616.047] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   616.049] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   616.049] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   616.049] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   616.049] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   616.049] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   616.049] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   616.049] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   616.049]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 0.0.2
[   616.049]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[   616.049] (**) FBDEV(1): claimed PCI slot 0@0:1:0
[   616.049] (II) FBDEV(1): using default device
[   616.049] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   616.049] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   616.049] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   616.049] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[   616.049] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[   616.049] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   616.049] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   616.049] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: VESA VGA (video memory: 1216kB)
[   616.049] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[   616.049] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[   616.049] (II) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 640x480 (pitch 640)
[   616.049] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 30.7 MHz, 36.9 kHz, 73.3 Hz
[   616.049] (II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0   30.72  640 672 752 832  480 484 488 504 -hsync -vsync -csync (36.9 kHz b)
[   616.049] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   616.049] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   616.049] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   616.049] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   616.050] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   616.050]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 1.0.0
[   616.050]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   616.050] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[   616.050] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[   616.050] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[   616.050] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[   616.050] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   616.050]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 1.1.0
[   616.050]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   616.050] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   616.050] (II) Unloading vesa
[   616.050] (II) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument (Screen blanking not supported by kernel - disabling)
[   616.050] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[   616.050] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[   616.051] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[   616.051] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[   616.051] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[   616.051] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[   616.051] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[   616.051] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   616.051] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[   616.051] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[   616.051] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[   616.052] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[   616.052] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[   616.052] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[   616.052] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[   616.053] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[   616.053] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[   616.053] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   616.053] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   616.053] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[   616.053] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[   616.054] (II) Initializing extension Present
[   616.054] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[   616.054] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[   616.054] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[   616.054] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   616.054] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[   616.054] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[   616.054] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   616.054] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[   616.088] (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[   616.088] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[   616.088] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   616.088] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[   616.088] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[   616.088] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[   616.124] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[   616.124] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   616.124] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[   616.124] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[   616.126] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   616.126]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.29.0
[   616.126]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   616.126]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[   616.126] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[   616.126] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   616.126] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[   616.126] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   616.128] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   616.128] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   616.128] (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
[   616.145] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0/event0"
[   616.145] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[   616.145] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   616.145] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   616.146] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   616.146] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   616.146] (II) config/udev: Adding input device QEMU QEMU USB Tablet (/dev/input/event2)
[   616.146] (**) QEMU QEMU USB Tablet: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[   616.146] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'QEMU QEMU USB Tablet'
[   616.146] (**) QEMU QEMU USB Tablet: always reports core events
[   616.146] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[   616.146] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   616.206] (II) event2  - QEMU QEMU USB Tablet: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   616.206] (II) event2  - QEMU QEMU USB Tablet: device is a pointer
[   616.206] (II) event2  - QEMU QEMU USB Tablet: device removed
[   616.237] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0627:0001.0001/input/input4/event2"
[   616.237] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "QEMU QEMU USB Tablet" (type: MOUSE, id 7)
[   616.237] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   616.237] (**) QEMU QEMU USB Tablet: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   616.237] (**) QEMU QEMU USB Tablet: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   616.237] (**) QEMU QEMU USB Tablet: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   616.298] (II) event2  - QEMU QEMU USB Tablet: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   616.298] (II) event2  - QEMU QEMU USB Tablet: device is a pointer
[   616.299] (II) config/udev: Adding input device QEMU QEMU USB Tablet (/dev/input/mouse0)
[   616.299] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   616.299] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   616.299] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event1)
[   616.299] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   616.299] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[   616.299] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[   616.299] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[   616.299] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   616.300] (II) event1  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   616.300] (II) event1  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[   616.301] (II) event1  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[   616.321] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input1/event1"
[   616.321] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[   616.321] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   616.321] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   616.322] (II) event1  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   616.322] (II) event1  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[   616.323] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse (/dev/input/event3)
[   616.323] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[   616.323] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse'
[   616.323] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: always reports core events
[   616.323] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[   616.323] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   616.324] (II) event3  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   616.324] (II) event3  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: device is a pointer
[   616.324] (II) event3  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: device removed
[   616.353] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3/event3"
[   616.353] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
[   616.353] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   616.353] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   616.353] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   616.353] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   616.354] (II) event3  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   616.354] (II) event3  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: device is a pointer
[   616.354] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse (/dev/input/mouse1)
[   616.354] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   616.355] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   636.736] (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
[   636.753] (II) event2  - QEMU QEMU USB Tablet: device removed
[   636.785] (II) event1  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[   636.801] (II) event3  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: device removed
[   636.834] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   636.834] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   636.834] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   636.834] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   636.838] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Comment: `sddm` should start the X server on its own, so you won't need `startx` when using `sddm`. In fact, if you have `startx` X11 session running, `sddm` might conflict with it. With `startx`, a typical session would be: text-based login -> `startx` -> GUI session -> end GUI session -> text-based logout. With `sddm` or similar, it should automatically start a X server and present a GUI login, and automatically return to GUI login whenever a GUI session ends.

Comment: @telcoM, thanks for the reply. Yes, that's how I've been logging in. But I tried starting sddm first. Any ideas how to troubleshoot sddm? Lightdm shows up as soon as I set it and reboot, but it won't log into KDE. As soon as I switch back, sddm doesn't show. I'm wondering if maybe the kubuntu-desktop from tasksel is trying to use gnome stuff. I got Lubuntu working on top of an identical server image with tasksel.

Comment: Look into `/var/log/` directory: is there a `sddm.log` or similar? If not, try `journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sddm.service` to find more information on what might be going wrong with sddm.

Answer (score 1):

```
[   616.044] (--) PCI:*(0@0:1:0) 1af4:1050:1af4:1100 rev 1, Mem @ 0xfc000000/8388608, 0xfd800000/16384, 0xfea14000/4096, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
```

Hmm, the log says the PCI vendor:product IDs of your GPU are `1af4:1050`. According to [the PCI ID Repository](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/1af4/1050), that is a Virtio virtual GPU. And all the Xserver driver modules that you seem to have available are `modesetting`, `fbdev`, `vesa` and a supplementary driver `fbdevhw`.

I've understood that `modesetting` would be the correct X11 base driver for virtio, but it would require that the `virtio_gpu` kernel module is loaded and providing the `/dev/dri/card0` device node. Based on the error message, it is not available:

```
[   616.049] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
```

Because `modesetting` cannot function without that device node, it fails and then `fbdev` is attempted as a second choice. It adds the  `vesa` driver layer and attempts to set up a display with resolution 640x480 (classic VGA):

```
[   616.049] (II) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 640x480 (pitch 640)
```

Perhaps I'm spoiled by modern high-DPI displays, but with modern GUI applications, I think using that resolution would feel like trying to fit a page of text on a postage stamp. And a virtio GPU should allow for easy dynamic resizing rather than defaulting to a fixed resolution anyway...

Perhaps `lightdm` defaults to using Wayland instead of X11, which might explain it working while `sddm` doesn't?

Comment: I think KDE/plasma is using Wayland now, and Lubuntu isnt so that might be the other way around.. so it could be the difference.. not sure how to troubleshoot that.. Im reading through virtio comments.. that driver could be a problem, but then lightdm shoudnt work, right?   (small resolution should be fine to start with, I can use xrandr)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I'll probably run lightdm and compare its log files to see if there's any hints in the differences.

Comment: Well, tracking down some things on lightdm I found a suggestion to use lightdm-gtk-greeter instead of the unfound lightdm-kde-greeter, and it logged in immediately after install. yay! thanks https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577597/346155